# php - replace width , height src from rss

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, preg-replace

I've already replaced a part of the `src` of the iframe.

```
<?php
foreach ( $x->channel->item as $entry ){
    $part_to_replace   = array("http://123.gr///www.youtube.com/");
        $replaced   = array("http://www.youtube.com/");
        $entry->description = str_replace( $part_to_replace, $replaced, $entry->description );  
        ?>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b">
                        <h4><?php echo $entry->title; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php  echo $entry->description; ?></p>
                </div>
        <?php   
        }
        ?>
```

This code runs great!Here's is a sample of the `iframes` i'm `parsing`

```
<iframe width="780" height="470" src="http://123.gr///www.youtube.com/embed/OZlyv68oNNM?rel=0&vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What i'm trying is to replace the value of the `width` and the `height` of the `iframe`.
I tied to run this code but the result was a white screen. Any ideas?

```
$part_to_replace1= ' /width=".*?"/ /height=".*?"/ ';
$part_to_replace2   = array("http://123.gr///www.youtube.com/");
$replaced1= 'width="250" height="200"';
$replaced2   = array("http://www.youtube.com/");
$entry->description = preg_replace($part_to_replace1 $part_to_replace2 , $replaced1 $replaced2, $entry->description);
```

Comment: You have a php syntax error here: `preg_replace($part_to_replace1 $part_to_replace2 , $replaced1 $replaced2, $entry->description);` Look at `$part_to_replace1 $part_to_replace2`, you cannot place two variables together like this. You get a white page probably because you have `display_errors` set to false.
Put this at the top of your php script:
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's is the code that  runs great!

```
foreach ( $x->channel->item as $entry ){
            $part_to_replace   = array("http://metar.gr///www.youtube.com/");
            $replaced   = array("http://www.youtube.com/");
            $entry->description = preg_replace( '/iframe width="[0-9]+" height="[0-9]+"/i ' , 'iframe width="100%" height="100%" ', $entry->description);
            $entry->description = str_replace( $part_to_replace, $replaced, $entry->description ); 

        ?>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b">
                        <h4><?php echo $entry->title; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php  echo $entry->description; ?></p>
                </div>
        <?php   
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your script returns a white screen because of a syntax error. You cannot deliver multiple parameters in that way.

This should to it for the width and height:

```
preg_replace('/width="[0-9]+" height="[0-9]+"/i', 'width="250" height="200"', $input_lines);
```

Comment: You should at least escape these double quotes.

Comment: @chris. Which of all the double quotes must escape?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed this. (copy & paste issue...)